# selecionar parte do JSON que foi filtrado no where

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, json

No banco de dados tenho um campo chamado recursos, nele guardo as permissões de um usuário, no formato Json:

```
[  
 {  
    "rota":"reserva",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"1",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show",
       "store",
       "update"
    ],
    "descricao":"Reservar",
    "controller":"ReservasController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"reserva",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"2",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Reservas",
    "controller":"ReservasController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"usuario",
    "sref":"oQueFazer",
    "ordem":"3",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Usuários",
    "controller":"UsuariosController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"feriado",
    "sref":"home.feriado",
    "ordem":"4",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show",
       "store",
       "update",
       "destroy"
    ],
    "descricao":"Feriados",
    "controller":"FeriadosController"
 },
 {  
    "rota":"sala",
    "sref":"home.sala",
    "ordem":"5",
    "recursos":[  
       "index",
       "show"
    ],
    "descricao":"Salas",
    "controller":"SalasController"
 }
]
```

Quando executo a consulta a abaixo, ele me dá o retorno correto de qual usuário tem a permissão:

```
SELECT recursos from perfis
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

Quase lá, com o `select` acima eu consigo a linha de registro que estou procurando, o problema que ele me mostrar toda a coleção de json que está no campo recursos. (Claro que ele ia fazer isso, foi o que pedi para ser executado).

Então para ele me trazer as permissões que são autorizadas para um usuário em determinado controller, eu fiz o select abaixo:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(recursos, '$[0].recursos') permite from perfis
WHERE
JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

E o retorno foi:

```
["index", "show", "store", "update"]
```

Ou seja, tudo OK, ele mostra as permissões que o usuário tem em determinado controller, O PROBLEMA é que ele mostrar as permissões da coleção de JSON da primeira linha `'$[0].recursos'` mas não é bem isso que estou querendo, quero retornar:

```
["index", "show", "store", "update", "destroy"]
```

Que é a permissão que o usuário tem para o controller `FeriadosController`

Ou seja, estou conseguindo varrer o controller para pesquisar no json, mas não estou conseguindo mostrar a parte do json que foi pesquisado, alguém tem solução pra isso, jpa passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando uma combinação de [`JSON_SEARCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract), [`JSON_UNQUOTE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) e a função de manipulação de string [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), acho que consegui chegar ao resultado desejado.

Partindo do princípio que a estrutura do JSON é conhecida, efetue uma busca por *FeriadosController* usando `JSON_SEARCH()` e manipule o resultado para substituir "controller" por "recursos". Use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` para retirar as aspas que o MySQL coloca no resultado e aí passe tudo para o `JSON_EXTRACT()`.

Não é bonito, mas funciona:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(recursos,                                          -- ["index", "show", "store", "update", "destroy"]
        JSON_UNQUOTE(                                               -- $[3].recursos
            REPLACE(                                                -- "$[3].recursos"
                JSON_SEARCH(recursos, 'one', 'FeriadosController'), -- "$[3].controller"
            'controller','recursos')
        )
    ) 
FROM PERFIS
WHERE
    JSON_CONTAINS(recursos, '{"controller": "FeriadosController"}');
```

---

***Detalhando:***

A função...

```sql
JSON_SEARCH(recursos, 'one', 'FeriadosController')
-- resultado: "$[3].controller"
```

...retorna o primeiro item ('one') encontrado no campo JSON `recursos`, que contém o valor `FeriadosController`.

Isso resulta, portanto, no seguinte REPLACE():

```sql
REPLACE('"$[3].controller"','controller','recursos')
-- resultado: "$[3].recursos"
```

...que substitui tudo o que é `controller` por `recursos`.

Entretanto, passar esse resultado para a `JSON_EXTRACT()` resulta em erro porque ele espera um `path` JSON, que não suporta as aspas contidas na string retornada pela `JSON_SEARCH()`.

Para tirar as aspas, o MySQL fornece então a função `JSON_UNQUOTE()`:

```sql
JSON_UNQUOTE('"$[3].recursos"')
-- resultado: $[3].recursos
```

Finalmente temos um *path* pronto para uso com `JSON_EXTRACT()`:

```sql
JSON_EXTRACT(recursos, '$[3].recursos')
-- resultado: ["index", "show", "store", "update", "destroy"]
```

Comment: @milrak-pereira-pessoa obrigado pelos edits! testei aqui usando a variável `@j` em vez de criar uma tabela e esqueci de mudar...

Comment: Tu é o cara, perfeito!
Se tu poder editar a publicação explicando melhor...

Comment: @MilrakPereiraPessoa, tem alguma dúvida específica? Editei tentando destrinchar melhor o que cada função faz isoladamente...